# Why is the y-intercept of $\frac {\sin(x)}{x}$ 1?

Tags: graphing-functions

I recently came across this function: $f(x) = \frac {\sin(x)}{x}$, and I graphed it on desmos. Why is the $y$-intercept $= 1$ despite $\sin(0)$ being divided by zero?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is not *defined* at $x=0$ but it does have a *limit* when $x \to 0$. This limit is the one defining the derivative of sin at $x=0$, a milestone in calculus:
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac {\sin(x)}{x} = 1
$$